# Linux red hat + replace PATH or word on scripts

Tags: linux, awk, sed, find, perl

Under folder:

```
/var/userTN/applo folder
```

I have around ~100 shell scripts that include the following PATH:

```
GLOBAL_PATH=/export/pop/PLW5
```

I want to replace the PATH on all the scripts under folder:

```
/var/userTN/applo
```

to this PATH

```
GLOBAL_PATH=/export/lld/sat
```

How to replace the PATH:

GLOBAL_PATH=/export/pop/PLW5

On all the files under folder:

/var/userTN/applo

With find + sed or other approach ? ( as Perl one liner solution )

remark:

Replace should be match exactly the “**GLOBAL_PATH=/export/pop/PLW5**”

For example

The PATH -> **GLOBAL_PATH=/export/pop/PLW51** ( should not replaced! )

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak 's#^\(GLOBAL_PATH=/export/\)pop/PLW5$#\1lld/sat#' /var/userTN/applo/*
```

The original file(s) will be backup up with `.bak` extension, if you don't want backup(s):

```
sed -i 's#^\(GLOBAL_PATH=/export/\)pop/PLW5$#\1lld/sat#' /var/userTN/applo/*
```

**Example:**

```
$ sed 's#^\(GLOBAL_PATH=/export/\)pop/PLW5$#\1lld/sat#' <<<'GLOBAL_PATH=/export/pop/PLW5'
GLOBAL_PATH=/export/lld/sat
```